# Is there a way to crawl all facebook fan pages?

Tags: php, facebook, web-crawler

Is there a way to crawl all facebook fan pages and collect some information? like for example crawling facebook fan pages and save their names, or how many fans, etc?
Or at least, do you have a hint of how this could be possibly done?

Comment: Been there, done that (well, not me, but you get the point). You might want to consider the legal issues before crawling Facebook in particular: http://slashdot.org/story/10/03/31/1430256/Facebook-Kills-Dataset-of-Crawled-Public-Profiles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First select a page that contains your desired category for pages:

**For Example:** http://www.facebook.com/pages/ or http://www.facebook.com/pages/?browse&ps=93

Then use a crawler to get all pages links.

Now you can parse each page separately using extracted links.

You can use [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for crawling.

Answer (score 2):

Write a crawler.

- I used Coca-Cola's page as an experiment:  http://www.facebook.com/cocacola?v=wall
- Parse out the "Fans" div, which contains an "All Fans" link.  View source in your web browser, it looks like this:
  /social_graph.php?node_id=40796308305&class=FanManager
- Turn that into a facebook URL and crawl it:
  http://www.facebook.com/social_graph.php?node_id=40796308305&class=FanManager
- Parse out the fans, then parse out the "Next page" link.
- Repeat, ad nauseum.
- Throttle your requests so facebook doesn't blacklist you.

Comment: RE: Stephen: Could you please explain your response in a little more detail? I'm not the most fluent programmer, but would like to be able to export the links to the profiles of all of the fans of a band into a csv file. Could you explain how you parse out the "fans" divider and view its source? In addition - how do you parse out the fans, then parse out the next page link?

Answer (score 1):

Download and run websphinx jar. Enter http://www.facebook.com/pages/ to Starting URLs and select the subtree as Crawl. Don't forget to increase Page Size and Page Timeout values. Higher number (100-200) of threads have higher chance of crawling more pages successfully.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/pages/ lists 'Suggested Pages', 'Liked Pages'. I don't see a way to get links to other Pages. One way is to crawl pages liked by friends. Any suggestions?