# Crawling Facebook for public Profiles & Fan Pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

I have requirement to search Facebook Public Profiles & Fan Pages for user provided search query.

For that I can either use Facebook Graph API ( as Graph Search API has not been released yet.) for the search query OR 
I scrap all info form Public Profiles & Fan Pages to my DB and perform search from my DB by crawling on Facebook.

In first option the drawback is Graph API doesn not return all public data and Graph Search API has not been released yet -[Is there an official Facebook Graph Search API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594245/is-there-an-offical-facebook-graph-search-api)

And if I go for Facebook crawling I really dont know how to crawl and extract public info from Facebook. I have seen a post here with similar scenario: [Is there a way to crawl all facebook fan pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565124/is-there-a-way-to-crawl-all-facebook-fan-pages).

But in my case I dont want to crawl a single page or category of pages but whole Facebook.

So could you please guide me here that how should I crawl whole Facebook for its public Info and is there any legal issues with it ?

Comment: there are some Social Media Management solutions out there on web which does this. And the advantage of this is fast results and efficient dashboards. And as I said the limitation of current version of Graph API is another reason for me thinking about Crawling option... but I would defintly would like to avoid it if there is another alternate solution to my problem.

Comment: There are many tools (nearly all the social network management tools) on web which crawls Facebook for its public profiles and Fan pages. So I think its safe to crawl Facebook for its private data... or is not ???